# "foreach" which works and looks like "sapply" in R

Tags: r, sapply

The `foreach` package in R provides a construct that resembles `sapply` and allows to run each evaluation in parallel. However, there are a few differences which don't suit my taste.

Then there is `mclapply` from the `parallel` package, but firstly, it doesn't work under Windows, and secondly, it works like `lapply` and not like `sapply`, so it is not a good tradeoff.

Is there a parallel implementation of sapply that (i) is multiplatform and (ii) works exactly like sapply?

Comment: what's wrong with `parSapply`?

Comment: Um... that I did not know about it? Thanks! (post as answer to get the credit)

Comment: You're welcome. I assumed you did, since you were talking about the `parallel` package.

Comment: Yeah, but my knowledge of it is... patchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the function `parSapply` from the parallel package.

The syntax is very similar to the "normal" `sapply`.

Comment: OK, and in the meanwhile, I know why I don't like it; unlike with `foreach` (well, kind of), I need to manually take care of exporting all needed variables. Worse; if I made a change to a variable after exporting with `clusterExport`, I will have no error, but the calculations will be wrong.  Moreover, I need to take care of all the libraries. Nonetheless, your answer was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I always fared best with `foreach` and `dopar`

Comment: I can't say why but foreach seems to me so counter intuitive and inconsistent that I always end up reading the documentation anew. This is purely subjective, but I vowed not to use it anymore. (i) no evaluation on lists (ii) unnamed list returned (iii) binary operator that combines a foreach object and an expression? But... why? Because the author found it cool to define his own operator?

Comment: I guess it really depends on your objective. But foreach has similarity with `lapply` and I always found it to be very efficient. But I don't want to start a discussion here. If you decide to post a question related to your objective and `foreach`, I'm happy to take a look.